# wifi0, wifi1 что значит?

Tags: wifi, router

Что такое `ath` и `eth` мне удалось выяснить, но пожалуй, уточню. Как я понимаю,

`eth` - ethernet interface служит для кабеля,
`ath` - служит для wifi,

соответственно, если роутер имеет несколько гнезд(припустим 2), то он будет иметь `eth0` и `eth1` интерфейсы. Если не так, то поправьте.

Если `ath` - WiFi, то, что такое само `wifi0`?

Answer (score 1):

Судя по вот [этой](https://compress.ru/article.aspx?id=19154) статье `wifi0` является **физическим** интерфейсом, а `ath0` относится к **виртуальному**. И, осмелюсь предположить, литер A в начале от слова Air или Atheros.